# How to center Swiper Slider thumbs with custom width?

Tags: center, thumbnails, swiper.js

I don't like the thumbs as provided by Swiper Slider. Therefor I want them to have a custom size (e.g. rectangle) and, most important, centered under the main slider.

The API call "centerSlides" does not set them centered, but light to the right.

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

No way to answer (To know why) - your thumbs do not align center.

Look at the example I made (Works fine // no issues):
https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/XWrBzMp

**In general:** most of the times you set the thumbs size by CSS:

```
.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
}
```

In this case change the slidesPerView under JS setting to `auto`:

```
  slidesPerView: "auto",
```

**SUM:** The size/width/styles of the thumbs not related to Swiper if you set `slidePerView: auto` (Use any styles you want). And of course, the size of the thumbs also related to the content inside (box-model).